# Matlab: reducing matrix size but minimizing the reduction of precision

Tags: matlab

I have a few variables that are of importance but are very large (20GB+) and that are roughly 900000x2000 Matrices. I would like to reduce the amount of rows/density Matrices so memory/time is conserved all the while minimizing the reduction of precision. I have read up on reducem but I don't think it suffices. Does anyone have any ideas how I can go about doing this? The Matrices are only 2-D if that helps.

Comment: We'll need some more information about your problem to be able to offer suggestions. What do these giant matrices represent?

Comment: The columns represent the time and the rows represent a variable that depends on time. In this case it's the temperature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your 900000 × 2000 array represents 2D sampled data, you can use `interp2` to resample it at lower resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yea the arrays are represent time and another variable. Would you know how I can be sure if I should use the linear setting with interp2 or interp2(___,method) and use 'nearest', 'cubic', 'makima', or 'spline' for the method? Or would you bet that interp2 with linear would be fine? Would you know how I could test them?

Comment: Another question, if I use interp2(V,k), would that just be the same as using interp2(V) k times (meaning interp2(interp2(interp2(...)))? Meaning, I save typing and with the 'k' option the interpolation would continue to reduce total memory of the array?